# Getting Error while Passing variables extracted from shell in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up Jenkins pipeline, but getting an error while  Passing variables extracted from the shell in the environment

```
    pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    PHP_CHANGE_SET = sh (script: "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep '.php'",returnStdout: true).trim()
  }
```

I am getting mentioned ERROR

```
    [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)

[Pipeline] sh

Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node

Error when executing failure post condition:

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:260)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:262)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:178)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
```

I need PHP files name only which are in commit  and store in variable

Comment: I am not sure if you can use a Pipeline step directly in your `environment` block, which is what the error is alerting you to. You would probably need to relocate that into your pipeline itself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you cannot use it outside node block. If you really need to do this and this is the first thing you want for your job(A), what you can do is make another job (B) and there run this command in the directory you want and then trigger this job(A). You can have "PHP_CHANGE_SET" as a parameter which you can pass from job B.